# What should i do in order to print level also in Breadth first search Algo.

Tags: javascript

What can be done in the below algo in order to print values level wise in binary tree.

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.breadthFirstTraversal = function() {
    console.log("Breadth First Traversal");

    var q = []
    q.push(this.root);//You don't need to write the root here, it will be written in the loop
    while (q.length > 0)
    {
        var n = q.shift();
        console.log(n.value); //Only write the value when you dequeue it
        if (n.left !=null)
        {
            q.push(n.left);//enqueue the left child
        }
        if (n.right !=null)
        {
            q.push(n.right);//enque the right child
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wanted to add this since it doesn't require the storage of the level of *each* corresponding node as in the solution above so it doesn't require you to add a property to your object. If you think about it the queue will have, at most, two different levels in it. So you only need one global marker to let you know if you are dealing with a new level and a flag to let you know if you should mark the new right or left node being pushed.

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.breadthFirstTraversal = function() {
        console.log("Breadth First Traversal");

var q = new Array();
q.push(this.root);

var printArray = [];
var printArray.push(this.root.value);

var newlevel = false;
var marker = 1;
var level = 0;


while(q.length > 0){


    if(marker==1){
        console.log("level: " + level);
        console.log(printArray);
        newlevel = true;
    }

     var n = q.shift();
     printArray.shift();

     marker -= 1;
     //console.log(n.value);

    if(n.left != null){
        q.push(n.left);
        printArray.push(n.left.value);

        if(newlevel){
            marker = q.length;
            level+=1;
            newlevel = false;
        }
    }

    if(n.right != null){
        q.push(n.right);
        printArray.push(n.right.value);

        if(newlevel){
            marker = q.length;
            level+=1;    
            newlevel = false;
        }
    }

}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Store level for each node,  and print them only when level changes:

```
BinarySearchTree.prototype.breadthFirstTraversal = function() {
    console.log("Breadth First Traversal");

    var q = [];
    var prevLevel = -1; // monitor level switch
    var byLevel = []; // store node values for printing
    this.root.level = 0; // set root level
    q.push(this.root);//You don't need to write the root here, it will be written in the loop
    byLevel.push(this.root.value);
    while (q.length > 0)
    {
        var n = q.shift();
        // Next level, print and reset
        if (n.level > prevLevel) {
            console.log(byLevel);
            byLevel = [];
            prevLevel = n.level;
        }
        if (n.left !=null)
        {
            n.left.level = n.level + 1;
            q.push(n.left);//enqueue the left child
            byLevel.push(n.left.value);
        }
        if (n.right !=null)
        {
            n.right.level = n.level + 1;
            q.push(n.right);//enque the right child
            byLevel.push(n.right.value);
        }
    }

    if (byLevel.length > 0) {
        console.log(byLevel);
    }
};
```